# MySql multiple queries or temporary table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need help from a SQL guru here...

I have data in the following format:

```
Key  Value
100  A
100  B
300  A
400  B
500  A
500  B
500  C
600  B
600  W
```

If I want to find all keys with A or B and A and B, but not AB with anything else...how would I do this?  Would I need a temp table or can I somehow join the table to itself?

EDIT:  The desired output would be Key 100 since it has A & B, Key 300 since it has A, Key 400 since it has B.  Not Key 500 because it also contains a C, and not key 600 because it also contains a W

Comment: What do you mean be `not AB`? and please add the required output.

Comment: 600 key has to be included or not? it has B and anything else, but not A

Comment: For normal sql is SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE value="A" OR value="B"

Comment: I think that the desired output from the given data should be ONLY 100, 300 and 400 (all other keys also have values like C or W).

Comment: This needs further clarification. Please add your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.`key`
FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.value in('A', 'B')
GROUP BY t1.`key`
HAVING COUNT(t1.value) = (SELECT COUNT(t2.value) 
                          FROM Table1 t2 
                          WHERE t1.`key` = t2.`key`)
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ae08/25)

This returns only the keys:

- Has `A` and `B` only, and nothing else so `key = 500` shouldn't be returned. But `key = 100` should be included.
- Has only `A`. As in `key = 300`.
- Has only `B` so `key = 600` shouldn't be returned since it contains one more value than `B` which is `w`. But `key = 400` should be included.

**Update:** How is this working

If any key has a value `IN('A', 'B')` then it could also contains other values as well.

Thats why I added the `HAVING` clause:

```
HAVING COUNT(t1.value) = (SELECT COUNT(t2.value) 
                          FROM Table1 t2 
                          WHERE t1.`key` = t2.`key`)
```

The `COUNT(t1.value)` is compared to the total `COUNT` of the values for the same key, by using a correlated subquery`SELECT COUNT(t2.value) FROM Table1 t2 WHERE t1.key = t2.key` , for each value `t1.value`. So if the current key contains values other than `'A', 'B'` then the `COUNT(t1.value)` won't equal to the `COUNT` of all values for the same key. For example the key = 500 has a count = 3 but using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.`key`
FROM table1 t1
WHERE t1.value in('A', 'B')
GROUP BY t1.`key`
```

Without the `HAVING` clause will include it as well, since it has either `A'` or 'B'. But the `HAVING` clause eliminates this key since it has a count = 3 not equal to 2.

Comment: Exactly...this is what I was looking for...thanks so much, I'g going to give it at shot.

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work.  Could you explain what t1 and t2 represent, if table1 is my table?  I'm getting an error "unknown value in WHERE clause".  I assume I have it set up incorrectly.

Comment: Absolute perfection...thanks for explaining it to me Mahmoud, I really appreciate your help.  I have been stumped on this for hours and you have provided an elegant solution.

Comment: @Mark - Its my pleasure. You're welcome any time. And thanks for this tricky question. I have learned something new from it.

Answer (score 0):

You should explain your question better, if i can understand correctly what you need you could use something like this:

```
SELECT Distinct K
FROM tab
WHERE
  value IN ('A', 'B') AND
  NOT EXISTS (SELECT Null from tab tab_1
              WHERE tab_1.K = tab.K and tab_1.value not in ('A', 'B'))
```